# Not able to see Business model and Business queries in SpagoBI Studio 5.2

Tags: business-intelligence, olap, olap-cube, spagobi

I want to create a business model in SpagoBI Studio but I am not able to find the options Business model and Business queries in the Studio Resource Navigator.

I am using SpagoBIStudio_5.2.0_linux64, and on Ubuntu 14.04.

I have created a new SpagoBI project in studio.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a business model in SpagoBI Studio.

You need to download also SpagoBI Meta (you can download it from the official website as well).

Spago BI Meta is still an Eclipse environment. Once created a new SpagoBI project, right click on the "Business Model" label, select "New model" and then follow the instruction in order to create your model.

Answer (score 0):

The file "SpagoBI.ini" must have the following structure:

```
-consoleLog
-vm
```

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin

```
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

where the address "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin" must correspond to you JDK address. That worked for me.

For more details refer to the README file.